# Where does ddns-confgen save its key(s)?

Tags: bind, dns-hosting, dynamic-dns

I hesitate to ask this question as I suspect I'm being stupid, but...

On Ubuntu server 22.04 running bind 9.18.18, when I run `ddns-confgen -k host.example.com`, it outputs some instructions referring to keys and configurations needed to for the named server config. It also includes the following:

```
# After the keyfile has been placed, the following command will
# execute nsupdate using this key:
nsupdate -k <keyfile>
```

The man page states:

> The key name can specified using -k parameter and defaults to ddns-key.  The generated key is accompanied by configuration text and instructions that can be  used  with  nsupdate and named when setting up dynamic DNS

Where is the "generated key" it refers to (there is nothing in the man page about a path or any option for that)? It doesn't appear in the directory I ran the command in, but I need that key to give to the `nsupdate` command when updating the zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Most of this answer was originally given by a user who has now deleted it.)*

Unlike key creation commands like `ssh-keygen`, `ddns-confgen` does not create or assume an output file will be made. Instead, it shows a key to you in the console along with some other instructions.

However, the instructions are not clear as to what format the key file should take for the `nsupdate -k` command. It is in fact the four lines given when you run `ddns-confgen` with the `q` option.

So, running `ddns-confgen -qk host.example.com > keyfile.key` would give you the file you need to give to `nsupdate -k` (without using copy/paste). Be aware, however, that each time you run `ddns-confgen` the key will change so you need to make sure you are giving the server the same key that `nsupdate` will use.

Bear in mind also that the instructions to use `nsupdate -k <keyfile>` may not work in the way you want. You need to read the documentation for `nsupdate` to provide various other options to update the zone.